# Can I edit the tasks list of the Right Click options on Windows 10 Taskbar Icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, context-menu, power-options

I would like to add the option to restore previous session on the tasks option, it this possible?

[image: Contex-menu on windows 10 taskbar icon]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for the question searching hard on this.

Found the feature called 'Jumplists' (This doesn't exist on windows 8.1). 
It can help you to add a new taskbar feature on right clicking the application icon:

These articles can help:

1. [Create costume jumplist](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30131/create-custom-windows-7-jumplists-for-apps-that-dont-have-one/)
2. [View jumplists nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html)
3. [More about with a 3rd party software](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/clear-and-disable-jump-lists-in-windows-7/)
4. [And another one](https://www.technorms.com/5119/windows-7-jumplists-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Your link led me to [Jumplist Extender](https://github.com/mazmazz/jumplist-extender) which did the trick for me on Windows 10. I use it to add suspend/resume items by calling an autohotkey script to suspend/resume the selected program.

Here's [the original community post](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/891756-win7-jumplist-extender-add-jumplists-to-any-program-release-04/) with more information, but unfortunately the jumplist pack links are no longer working.

Just wanted to clarify things by sharing the software github page and a little more info.